# Golang Marshal/Unmarshal XML without loosing data

Tags: xml, go

I need to Marshal/Unmarshal the below XML. Originally I had tried using the `innerxml` tag but that only solved half my problem... as I ran into this issue for the `Root` elements attributes: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9519

This has become quite difficult to get XML to Marshal/Unmarshal to a struct. In my specific case I do not care about the structure of the XML... but I do need to `Marshal/Unmarshal` the XML without loosing any data... and no I cannot just manually read the XML as a string... it must work when calling the `Marshal/Unmarshal` functions as shown in the example below.

```xml
<Root xmlns="ns1" xmlns:xsi="xsi1">
    <child value="value1" />
    <another value="value2" />
</Root>`
```

```golang
type Root struct {
    XMLNS  string   `xml:"xmlns,attr"`
    XSI string `xml:"xmlns:xsi,attr"`
    Content string   `xml:",innerxml"`
}
    var v Root
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(v)

    b, err := xml.Marshal(v)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
```

It would also be acceptable to simply Marshal/Unmarshal the entire object to a string... to a type such as the below

```golang
type MyXml sting
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. You haven't specified explicitly what the problem or error is. What is the expected and the actual output? Which data are you losing?

Comment: Did you read the linked github issue?

Comment: Nope, I did not.

Comment: Namespace prefixes do not marshal correctly

Comment: For namespace prefixes you can use custom [`xml.MarshalerAttr`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml@go1.17.7#MarshalerAttr). You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314105/generate-xml-document-from-an-xml-template/49327471#49327471), especially take a look at the `SoapenvAttr` type and its `MarshalXMLAttr` implementation.

Comment: thank you... that seems to have worked